# Jquery help counting checked checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I am trying to count the checkhed checkboxes. See her: http://jsfiddle.net/2bCdR/2/
The Jquery counter does not work and does also deactive the other Jquery.

My Jquery {

```
$.each($('div.category'), function () {
var categoryDiv = $(this);
function countChecked() {
  var n = $("categoryDiv input:checked").length;
  $("categoryDiv #counter").text(n);
}
}
countChecked();

$(":checkbox").click(countChecked);
```

My HTML

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/" method="get"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>

        <div class="menuitem category">
            <label for="search_company1">company1</label>
            <input name="search[company1_is_true]" type="hidden" value="0" />
            <input id="search_company1_is_true" name="search[company1_is_true]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
            <div id="counter"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="menuitem category">
            <label for="search_company3">company3</label>
            <input name="search[company3_is_true]" type="hidden" value="0" />
            <input id="search_company3_is_true" name="search[company3_is_true]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
            <div id="counter"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="hidediv">
            <div class="menuitem">
                <label for="search_company2">company2</label>
                <input name="search[company2_is_true]" type="hidden" value="0" />
                <input id="search_company2_is_true" name="search[company2_is_true]" type="checkbox" value="1" />

            </div>
        </div>
        <input id="search_submit" name="commit" style="display:none;" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - You have duplicate 'counter' div IDs. You should change them to classes (IDs should never be duplicated).

2 - You do not need a loop. A single click handler with appropriate traversal will do it.

```
$(":checkbox").click(function() {

    // find closest category parent div
    var $cat = $(this).closest(".category");

    // get checkbox within category, check length
    var len = $cat.find(":checkbox:checked").length;

    // update the div's counter
    $cat.find(".counter").text(len);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mvdnj/1/

Comment: There is a problem with that Jquery because if the div is clicked the checkbox gets checked but it the counter dos not update. The counter should update when clicked on the div and the checkbox

Comment: The checkboxes in the minimenu is not either added to the counter

Comment: Change the labels for the checkboxes to match the IDS of the checkboxes and you don't need the divs to be clickable.

Answer (score 3):

```
var checked = $(':checkbox:checked', '.menuitem, .hidediv').length;
```

Check a working example out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/W28JZ/11/)

Comment: IT should not count all checkboxes there is 1 counter for each menuitem and it should count all checked checkboxes that is in the hidediv and the menuitems checkbox